# powershell confusion when comparing data

Tags: powershell, compare

**My script is searching in powershell v2 directories bigger than N size prompting user where to look**

```
1 write-host -foreground green "path to search"
2 $location = read-host
3 write-host -foreground green "how about the size (GB)"
4 $size = read-host
5 $unit = "GB"
6 $threshold = $size + $unit
7 $fso = New-Object -COM 'Scripting.FileSystemObject'
8
9 Get-ChildItem $location -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object 
{
    $_.PSIsContainer -and $fso.GetFolder($_.FullName).Size -gt $threshold
}
```

**Running the script, will throw an error:**

```
Bad argument to operator '-gt': Could not compare "10689" to "1GB". Error: "Cannot convert value "1GB" to type "System
Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."".
```

**But if I'll run the line 7 and line 9 directly in Powershell app as this:**

```
PS C:\Users\Billy> $fso = New-Object -COM 'Scripting.FileSystemObject'
PS C:\Users\Billy\Desktop> Get-ChildItem c:\users -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -and $fso.GetFolder($_.FullName).Size -gt 1GB}
```

**It seems when I'm providing the "1GB" from CLI, it works. Why?**

Comment: `$threshold = ([Int] $size) * 1gb`

Comment: 1GB is a number (1073741824). "1GB" is a string.

Comment: right. i'm such a dumb. thanks!